# Is there any decent way to Decorate models returned from a Magento `[model]_load_after`event?

Tags: magento, events, decorator

I'm trying to overwrite some methods in models, and I'm on a mission to avoid overwrites and rewrites of models for maximum compatibility with other modules.

I figured the best way would be to simply decorate models after they are loaded from Magento, however as far as I can tell because of the way the observer pattern in Magento is written it's impossible to accomplish this. ( As Magento always returns the reference to `$this` ), and the lack of interfaces might also cause trouble later down the road? See this partial of Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php

```
/**
 * Processing object after load data
 *
 * @return Mage_Core_Model_Abstract
 */
protected function _afterLoad()
{
    Mage::dispatchEvent('model_load_after', array('object'=>$this));
    Mage::dispatchEvent($this->_eventPrefix.'_load_after', $this->_getEventData());
    return $this;
}
```

My question boils down to the title, is there a decent way of accomplishing this?, or am I simply stuck with rewrites :(?

The path I would like to take is;

- On event `[model]_load_after`
- return `new Decorator($event->getObject())`

Where the decorator class in my case would be something like;

```
public function __construct(Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Invoice $model)
{
    parent::__construct($model); // sets $this->model on parent class, see below
}

// overwrite the getIncrementId method
public function getIncrementId()
{
    return '12345';
}

// partial of parent class

public function __call($method, array $args)
{
    return call_user_func_array(array($this->model, $method), $args);
}
```

And just some pseudo-code for extra clarification;

```
$model = Mage::getModel('sales/order_invoice')->load(1);
echo get_class($model);

Namespace_Decorator **INSTEAD OF** Mage_Sales_Model_...

echo $model->getIncrementId();
'12345' **INSTEAD OF** '1000001' ( or whatever the format might be )
```

Thanks for your time reading / commenting, I really hope there actually *is* a way to accomplish this in a clean fashion without making use of code overrides or rewrites of models.

**Edit: extra clarification**

Basically what I would like is to return an instance of the Decorator in a few cases, the sales_invoice being one of them and customer the other. So when any load() call is made on these models, it will always return the instance of the Decorator instead of the Model. Only method calls that the decorator overrides would be returned, and any other method calls would "proxied" through __call to the decorated object.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I got your question right but here goes.
I think you can use the event `[model]_load_after` and simply do this:

```
$object = $event->getObject();
$object->setIncrementId('12345');
```

Or if you want to use a decorator class make it look like this:

```
public function __construct(Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Invoice $model)
{
    parent::__construct($model);
    $model->setIncrementId($this->getIncrementId());
}
public function getIncrementId()
{
    return '12345';
}
```

I know that this is not exactly a decorator pattern but it should work.
I know that when adding a new method to the 'decorator' class you need to add it to attach data to the main model.
This is just my idea. I haven't got an other.

**[EDIT]**
You can try to rewrite the `load` method on the object to make it return what you need. But I wouldn't go that way. You can end up screwing a lot of other things.
I don't think there is an other way to do it because `load` always returns the current object no mater what you do in the events dispatched in the method. see `Mage_Core_Model_Abstract::load()`

```
public function load($id, $field=null)
{
    $this->_beforeLoad($id, $field);
    $this->_getResource()->load($this, $id, $field);
    $this->_afterLoad();
    $this->setOrigData();
    $this->_hasDataChanges = false;
    return $this;
}
```

By making it return `new Decorator($this)`, you might achieve what you need, but just make sure that when calling `$model->doSomething()` and `doSomething()` is not a method in your decorator you still end up calling the original method on the model.

Comment: Yes I'm aware that this is possible, however that would require to ( in my use-case ) replacing the increment_id in the [model]_load_after event, and restore the original value on [model]_before_save ( and avoid a ->save() call being made in the case Magento would detect this as an actual "change" ( see origData  ).

However I'd really really prefer not going this way, I just want to "overwrite" what it displays, but I'm not a fan of using local overrides or rewrites for this.

Comment: updated the question with an extra clarification at the bottom.

Comment: I'm sorry for the downvote but this is something is already known to me, if there are no decent solutions I'll bring it back up.

Comment: @wtfzdotnet. I've added a new possible solution. You can try that one. I don't see any reason for downvoting the original answer, just because you knew that approach. But anyway, it's your right to do it. :)

Comment: Thanks for the update, this one gets close but I'd still have to rewrite the models. I think we can both agree that this is just impossible :-), I'll be waiting a bit longer to see if anyone else might have a genius idea. Otherwise I will accept your answer.